# HibernateCallback implementation

Tags: spring, hibernate

Consider code

```
public List<Product> listProducts(){

    HibernateCallback callBack=new HibernateCallback(){

    public Object doInHibernate(Session session){
       Query query=session.createQuery("from Product");
       return query.list();
     }
    };
    return (List<Product>)hibernateTemplate.execute(callBack);
}
```

Is there anything wrong with above code? In *eclipse Helios* it is showing following error:

```
The type new HibernateCallback(){} must implement the inherited abstract method HibernateCallback.doInHibernate(Session)
```

`doInHibernate()` is implemented then why it showing the above error?

Comment: Make sure that `Session` is `org.hibernate.Session`, not something else (e.g. `org.hibernate.classic.Session`).

Comment: @axtavt: yes i mistakenly did this.Above change has solved the problem. Can u please post ur comment as answer so that i can accept this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that `Session` is `org.hibernate.Session`, not something else (e.g. `org.hibernate.classic.Session`).

The pair of `org.hibernate.Session` and `org.hibernate.classic.Session` is especially tricky - since the latter interface extends the former one, accidential mistake of this kind doesn't cause other problems and cannot be easily noticed.